# Which are properties of the "flip-one-bit" relation for two strings?

Tags: logic, relations, binary

This question came up on my Exam Practice sheet. I understand the properties of the relations, but I'm having trouble doing it using strings. I put down my answers to the questions below. I would appreciate it if anybody could confirm or deny (and then explain) my answers and reasoning.

The flip-one-bit relation: define a binary relation *R* on a set of length-4 bit strings where *s1Rs2* if and only if flipping a single bit (0 to 1 / 1 to 0) of *s1* produces *s2*

**A)** Give an example of two strings *s1* and *s2* such that *s1 R s2* holds.

s1 = 1001 , s2 = 1000

**B)** Give an example of two strings such that *s1 R s2* does **not** hold.

s1 = 1101 ,  s2 = 1010

**C)** Is *R* reflexive? Explain.

No because s1Rs1 is false.

**D)** Is *R* symmetric? Explain.

Yes because s1Rs2 is true and s2Rs1 is also true.

**E)** Is *R* anti-symmetric? Explain.

No, because even though s1Rs2 is true and s2Rs1 is true s1 != s2

**F)** Is *R* transitive? Explain.

No, example:

s1Rs2 = (1001)R(1000) is **true** , 
s2Rs3 = (1000)R(1100) is **true**, 
s1Rs3 = (1001)R(1100) is **false**.

**G)** Is *R* an equivalence relation? Explain

No, it is not transitive.

**H)** Is R a partial order? Explain.

No, it is not reflexive or transitive.

Comment: Check your aswer to part G.  In part D you correctly concluded that $R$ is symmetric.  So the conclusion in part G is correct, but the reason you gave is not.

Comment: For C, D, and E you are simply stating the definition and then asserting that R does or does not satisfy it. For the negative cases you can provide a counter-example like you did for F. For D though, you need an actual argument.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Oops, just changed it to reflect that.

Comment: @DerekElkins Right, I'll provide examples to those. I'm just hoping the logic is right, aka the relations are in fact correct.